# Printing html form values in another html document through j.s function

Tags: html, forms, document

I have created a form in Html .and saved all the values in local storage by using setItem() . Now i am facing a problem to print these values in a new Html document namely result.html

Answer (score 0):

To display information on a new page you will need to use a server side scripting language such as PHP, ASP.

To do this you will need to set your form on the HTML page to link to a new .php file.

```
<form action='result.php' method='POST'> 
    <input type='text' name='name' />
```

Then, on your PHP file you need to call the information from the form input:

```
$_POST['name'];
```

From here, you can echo this information to display :)